# Как в Битрикс 24 отключить оповещения на почту?

Tags: битрикс24

При создании задачи в Битрикс 24 на почту отправляется уведомление.

Как отключить эту функцию?

Answer (score 0):

Уведомления приходят на почту только если пользователь спустя 15 минут не просмотрел его в "Центре уведомлений". Для настройки получения уведомлений:

1. Откройте центр уведомлений (нажатие на колокольчик)
2. В левой стороне нажимаем на шестеренку. Откроются настройки.
3. Снимаем галочку возле "Электронную почту". Нажимаем сохранить.